# Can we merge all of our current tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

According to [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

> All good tag synonyms should eventually be merged.

Currently, we have [60 non-merged, and stable synonyms](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest) (see [EvilGenius's comment](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/can-we-merge-all-of-our-current-tag-synonyms?noredirect=1#comment9280_4905) why not 61). Stable in the sense more than two months working as synonyms and without complaints.

[This](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/should-we-be-merging-our-non-merged-tag-synonyms-as-a-matter-of-course) is a Q/A in Cross Validated Meta (which I participated) that elaborates on why the community there decided to merge all synonyms in the main site (and also in meta).

Is there anything preventing us for merging tag synonyms here in GIS SE?

Comment: I don't see a reason not to in general, as long as the synonyms stay in place. Otherwise, I could see some of them coming back as normal tags. Also, that list needs some review. [tag:arcgisscripting] and [tag:arcpy] are very similar/related but they are two different python libraries with different functionalities [that can even used side by side](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172598/forcing-python-toolbox-tool-to-break-loop-and-do-cleanup-when-user-clicks-cancel/172911#172911).

Comment: @EvilGenius, tks. The merged synonyms stay in place, see for example, [tag:coordinate-system] (https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/coordinate-system/synonyms). About 'acrgisscripting' and 'arcpy' they should be disregarded from my question, because you are raising a dispute right now about them being synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, the desirability of eventually turning tag synonyms into tag merges, has already been documented via a Meta SE FAQ at [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work), and so I have merged all but two of the 60 or so tag pairs that you mentioned.

I'm not convinced that [arcgisscripting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgisscripting)=>[arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) is any more a special case than [sextante-qgis-plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sextante-qgis-plugin)=>[qgis-processing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-processing), and I think both merges are pragmatic and should proceed, but I will defer merging those for now.

I am leaving the synonyms in place after each merge.

Comment: @AndreSilva I'm looking at each pair as I find time.  Some have been part of Meta discussions previously so I try to check that I am respecting those discussions before I hit the merge button.

Comment: I've merged all but the two "special" cases mentioned in my answer.  I'm happy to merge those too, if it is agreed that they should not be treated as special.  @EvilGenius has suggested that one of them needs review.