# Keep or delete [qgis-3] version tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, version-tags

We have a versionless tag for [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) and individual tags for each minor version, eg [qgis-2.18](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2.18), [qgis-3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.0) and [qgis-3.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.2).

Now there's a new tag, [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3).

**Should [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) be merged with one of the other qgis tags? If so, which one?**

Pros: This would be consistent with how we've handled version tags in the past. QGIS already has a lot of tags. [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) currently has only two questions, so it would be easy to get rid of this tag.

**Or should we keep [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) as a standalone tag, to refer to the entire 3.x series?**

Pros: The 3.x series is a major change from the 2.x series. The logo changed color from yellow to green, many new features were added, and many old features work differently.

Answer (score 24):

I believe that QGIS 3.0 and QGIS 3.2 are essentially the same series. QGIS 3.4 comes out 26/10/2018 and also belongs in the same series.

Additionally, a lot of plugins and features are being ported to the new versions. I believe our energy would be best used to try and optimise the latest release.

I believe only 2 tags are needed going forwards: [qgis-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2) and [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3). The [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) tag should refer to the entire "3.x" series. The tags [qgis-3.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.0), [qgis-3.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.2) and [qgis-3.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.4) should all be merged into [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3).

I believe the tag [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) is not specific enough and will pose the same problem when QGIS 4 comes out in a couple of years.

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear in [MapInfoNewbie's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/keep-or-delete-qgis-3-version-tag/4928#4928) what to do with the [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tag, hence, I assume the suggestion there (in response to what was asked in question) is just to eliminate/synonymize **minor** version tags such as [qgis-2.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2.8) and [qgis-3.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3.2) in favour of respectively **major** version tags [qgis-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2) and [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3).

I believe we should keep [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) and use version tags only when subject of question is specific to one version or the other. On the other hand, the software version being used can always be specified in the post's body.

The same as suggested in @underdark's answer in [Dealing with Q&As using deprecated/non-existent PyQGIS API functions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/dealing-with-qas-using-deprecated-non-existent-pyqgis-api-functions)

> In my opinion, answers should specify the version they are written for. If the API changes over time, an update to the answer or a new answer should be added to point out the API change.
>
> I'm not a friend of having ten copies of the same question for ten QGIS versions because it makes it impossible to find and maintain answers.

Answer (score 1):

In support of [MapInfoNewbie's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/keep-or-delete-qgis-3-version-tag/4928#4928) I would favor to completely remove *either* all supplement tags ([qgis.x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis.x) & [qgis-x.x](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-x.x)) *or* the version-less tag [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis), **but then I'd like the idea of maintaining major version tags [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) & [qgis-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2) better**, with the reason being that those versions *do* have significant differences in most aspects of the software.

I also do have the faith that most users will assume the right tag this way, contrary to the current situation *and* with the continuation of the version-less tag.

The very rare cases where a question refers to QGIS in general, e.g. as a project (and thus possibly being fit for a version-less tag) could be intercepted with e.g. a [qgis-project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-project) tag? Does it or do similar tags exist already, and might there be the need to clean up as well?

I have no knowledge of the tag systems capabilities and wouldn't know if this is the way to do this, but: would it be possible to turn all [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tags prior to the release date of QGIS 3 into the major version [qgis-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2) tag? Would that, in  consequence, mean to *manually* alter all chronologically following tags according to the major version?