# How to treat questions/answers that can be slightly modified to become useful in future?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

On the GIS SE there are questions as well as answers based on QGIS Software versions: 1,2,3 (maybe 4 in the upcoming decade).

These questions/answers I would probably split into three groups, that are:

1. only valid for a particular QGIS version (in future they could become [closed])
2. valid for all QGIS versions
3. not yet changed (not yet uniform), so they are primarily belong to 1 but can become 2

So my question is pretty straightforward: Whether i/we should or should not update/improve/modify/adjust/edit/work on questions/answers from group 3?

If you ask me why? Because

- it might prevent the GIS SE from an overflow of identical/similar/analogical/homogeneous question/answers
- it might keep one main question/answer up-to-date
- IMHO a probability of using older QGIS version in future declines

I have seen similar topics regarding the QGIS tags and Software versions:

- [Keep or delete [qgis-3] version tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/keep-or-delete-qgis-3-version-tag)
- [Asking same question for newer version?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/asking-same-question-for-newer-version)

but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I think both this and https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4436/115 are about “timeless” Q&As and our aspiration for many of our Q&As to asymptote towards being such.  Consequently, I think it is a duplicate, and am wondering whether  you can explain more about why you think that it is only a similar rather than duplicate question.